# BabelJS path docs/reference

Tags: babeljs, babel-plugin

I'm trying to understand a particular babel plugin, so I started reading the [babel plugin development handboook](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md). I'd now like to find a reference for all the methods and things available on the `path` object that a visitor method gets, but I can't seem to find that. I'd aszsume it's somewhere in the `babel-traverse` package, but that package's link in the handbook points to the repo, which has very little info, the repo says "for more info, see the website", and then the website just links back to the handbook. Is there a reference available anywhere? Googling "bable path reference docs" or related searches is proving fruitless as well.